# Cakephp 4 - authentication 2 - How to test login?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I have a login method that works fine with [authentication 2](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html#building-a-login-action).

I need to write an integration test of the login method, but it fail with FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND

Here is the test:

```
public function testLoginOk()
{
    $this->enableCsrfToken();
    $this->enableSecurityToken();
    $this->enableRetainFlashMessages();

    $this->post('/users/login', [
        'user_login' => 'user1',
        'password' => 'P!tU!i!ZIMI&',

    ]);
    $this->assertFlashMessage(__('You are connected'));
}
```

In the fixture, the user1 password if hasshed
[

```
'id' => 1,
'user_login' => 'user1',
'user_pass' => 'e430ff579ef1db71e654852e548e0f327b0e3d18', # P!tU!i!ZIMI&
'user_status' => 1,
...
```

In Application.php

```
        $fields = [
            'username' => 'user_login',
            'password' => 'password'
        ];

        // Load the authenticators, you want session first
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Cookie');
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => $fields,
            'loginUrl' => '/users/login'
        ]);
```

I can't figure out why the test do not work, any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: What identifiers with what hasher and resolver config are you loading into the service?

Comment: $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields'));
with the default hasher.
Perhaps the salt is not the same during tests, so the hash password in fixture is not correct ? (I copy the hash password from prod database ...)

Comment: The [default password hasher](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/password-hashers.html#default) uses bcrypt, your fixture seems to use sha1.